# Oracle PL/SQL String Formatting

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I started learing Oracle PL/SQL and I downloaded Oracle Database 10g Express with same examples and questions.

There is a question which I could not solve.

Question is:

> Write an SQL query to retrieve the first name, last name, and the code
>   of each employee where the code of an employee is found as follows:
>   Firstly remove all occurrences of the characters “i” and “l”, then,
>   concatenate the first six letters of the name, a dash sign “-“, and
>   the last six characters of the last name where only the first and last
>   character of the code should be uppercase. If the name does not
>   contain six letters, put underscores (“*”) to the end of the piece; if
>   the last name does not contain six letters, put underscores (“*”) to
>   the start of the piece. Order the list according to the last name, and
>   then according to the name.

**OUTPUT MUST BE LIKE THAT**

[image]

**I wrote something but it is totaly wrong and not clear. Which parts should I fix?**

---

```
SELECT employees.first_name, employees.last_name,
replace(replace(first_name,'l',''),'i'),
initcap(substr(rpad(employees.first_name,6,'_'),1,6)) || '-' ||

case when length(employees.last_name)>4
then lower(substr(employees.last_name,-5,4))
else lower(substr(lpad(employees.last_name,5,'_'),-5,4)) end ||
upper(substr(employees.last_name,-1,1)) code

FROM employees
ORDER BY last_name, first_name;
```

This is my output(WRONG)
[image]

Comment: In `replace(replace(first_name,'l',''),'i')` what are you **actually** replacing "`i`" with?

Comment: actually i want to replace it with null or "" but if i add replace character it is giving error about "parameter number is too many"

Comment: Then why didn't you?  Why you just replaced "`l`" with empty string but not "`i`"?

Comment: because as far as i know replace function takes 2 parameters

Comment: Look at **your own code**. How many parameters your outer replace has?

Comment: See http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php

Comment: If you are just learning sql, start with something easier than that question.  I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: Learning SQL is good. Learning troubleshooting is better. The first step to troubleshooting is 'divide and conquer'. Which in this case means reduce your expression to something much simpler, inspect it and then wrap it in the next level of expression, inspect it, and so on until you get the correct answer. So first of all check that `replace(first_name,'l','')` returns what you expect (by putting it into it's own column) and go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can write it like this:

```
select first_name, last_name, f
       ||'-'
       ||substr(l, 1, length(l) - 1)
       ||upper(substr(l, -1)) code
  from (select first_name, last_name,
               initcap(rpad(substr(translate(first_name, 'xil', 'x'), 1, 6), 6,
                       '_')) f,
               lpad(substr(translate(last_name, 'xil', 'x'),
                           greatest(-6, -length(translate(last_name, 'xil', 'x')))), 6,
                          '_')
                          l
          from employees);
```

i've assumed you only wanted to replace `i` and `l` and not also `I` and `L`. translate will act the same as `replace(replace(str, 'l', ''), 'i', '')` in this case.

Comment: But it is not giving expected output. For example column name is very complicated. Column names should like above picture :)

Comment: @hakiko the example was for the code part. see here to add the other two original columns: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1fba7/1

Comment: this is nice solution but I already have datas, tables, columns. In your link you created it with your best. :) Question about existed datas. Oracle Express gives ready database for doing examples :)

Comment: whattt only you added "f" and all visuality has changed. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

This code exactly follows your requirement:
Replace the column name and the table name with the desired values

```
SELECT ENAME,
       JOB,
          INITCAP (RPAD (REPLACE (REPLACE (ENAME, 'I'), 'i'), 6, '_'))
       || '-'
       || LPAD (
             reverse (
                INITCAP (
                   SUBSTR (reverse ( (REPLACE (REPLACE (JOB, 'I'), 'i'))),
                           1,
                           6))),
             6,
             '_')
          code
  FROM emp 
  ORDER BY JOB, Ename
```

Answer (score 0):

This code that somewhat follows your original logic:

```
SELECT e."First_Name", e."Last_Name",
       initcap(rpad(replace(replace(e."First_Name", 'l'), 'i'),6,'_'))
       || '-' ||
       reverse(initcap(reverse(lpad(replace(replace(e."Last_Name", 'l'), 'i'),6,'_')))) "Code"
FROM Employees e
ORDER BY e."Last_Name", e."First_Name";
```

I'm using `REVERSE` twice so I can use `INITCAP` for the last name as well. I also omitted the 3rd parameter of `REPLACE` since the function uses empty string by default.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9e5c/1) I build from the part of your data. Feel free to add more data.